# Como trazer registros de um LEFT JOIN mesmo não obedecendo o WHERE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, null

Exemplificando, tenho a

`tabela_A`:

```
cod     nome
1       stack
2       overflow
3       stackoverflow
```

e `tabela_B`:

```
cod_tabela_A    ano     mes valor
1               2016    1   100     
1               2016    2   115
2               2016    1   90
```

Quando efetuado um LEFT JOIN, me retorna o seguinte, de forma correta:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela_A a
LEFT JOIN tabela_B b ON a.cod = b.cod_tabela_A

cod     nome            cod_tabela_A    ano     mes     valor
1       stack           1               2016    1       100     
1       stack           1               2016    2       100     
2       overflow        2               2016    1       90
3       stackoverflow   NULL            NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Caso eu adicione a cláusula WHERE:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela_A a
LEFT JOIN tabela_B b ON a.cod = b.cod_tabela_A
WHERE ano = 2016 AND mes = 2
```

Me retorna um único registro, de forma correta:

```
cod     nome            cod_tabela_A    ano     mes valor
1       stack           1               2016    2   100
```

Porém o que preciso é que quando não obedecer os valores indicados no WHERE, me retorne NULL:

```
cod     nome            cod_tabela_A    ano     mes     valor
1       stack           NULL            NULL    NULL    NULL        
1       stack           1               2016    2       NULL        
2       overflow        NULL            NULL    NULL    NULL
3       stackoverflow   NULL            NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Há alguma forma de obter este resultado?

Comment: Retire o `WHERE` e deixe só `and b.ano = 2016 AND  b.mes = 2`

Comment: O where é porquê possui outras condições dentro dele, mas seguindo o que foi dito, o resultado saiu como esperado.

Comment: Não entendi o voto negativo...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Praticamente você só precisa retira o `Where`, pois ele faz o filtro final, ou seja, só as linhas que tenha o filtro do `Where` retomará , se você usar o `AND` logo após o `ON` do `LEFT JOIN` será retornado tudo da `tabela_A` e as condições da `tabela_B`.

> ON a.cod = b.cod_tabela_A
>       and ano = 2016 AND mes = 2

```
declare @tabela_A table
(
    cod int,
    nome varchar(100)
)

declare @tabela_B table
(
    cod_tabela_A     int,
    ano int,
    mes int,
    valor int
)

insert into @tabela_B values
(1        ,       2016   , 1  , 100  ),   
(1     ,          2016  ,  2  , 115),
(2   ,            2016  ,  1  , 90)

insert into @tabela_A values
(1 ,      'stack'),
(2 ,      'overflow'),
(3 ,     ' stackoverflow')


SELECT * FROM @tabela_A a
LEFT JOIN @tabela_B b ON a.cod = b.cod_tabela_A
and ano = 2016 AND mes = 2
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: +1 boa resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que o código abaixo resolva o seu problema, só uma dica, sei que você quer que retorne todos os campos de ambas tabelas mas às vezes duas tabelas tem algum campo com o mesmo nome e acaba dando erro de campo duplicado. Trabalho com banco de dados há anos e vejo isso acontecer muito. Segue o que você precisa, coloquei usando a padronização que uso na empresa.

```
 SELECT A.cod AS codA, A.nome AS nomeA, 
        B.cod AS codB, B.codigo_tabela_a AS cod_tb_A, 
        B.ano AS anoB, B.mes AS mesB, 
        B.valor AS valB
 FROM @tabela_a A
 LEFT JOIN tabela_b B ON A.cod = B.cod_tabela_a AND B.ano = 2016 AND B.mes = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você pode usar **IF** sem o WHERE.
Você trará todos os resultados, sendo que
**SE** atender o critério (b.ano = 2016 AND b.mes = 2) retorna o valor original,
 caso contrário **NULL**.

*Separei com linhas em branco para facilitar a compreensão.

SELECT a.cod, a.nome,
**IF(** b.ano = 2016 AND b.mes = 2, b.cod_tabela_A, NULL) AS **cod_tabela_A**,
**IF(** b.ano = 2016 AND b.mes = 2, b.ano, NULL) AS **ano**,
**IF(** b.ano = 2016 AND b.mes = 2, b.mes, NULL) AS **mes**,
**IF(** b.ano = 2016 AND b.mes = 2, b.valor, NULL) AS **valor**
FROM tabela_A a
LEFT JOIN tabela_B b ON a.cod = b.cod_tabela_A

Onde coloquei NULL você pode usar outro valor como ' ' para deixar em branco.
IF( b.ano = 2016 AND b.mes = 2, b.ano, ' ')

Answer (score -1):

Eu fiz dessa forma e deu certo, mas não sei se te atenderia

```
declare @retorna_dado int,
@ano int,
@mes int
set @ano = 2016
set @mes = 2
set @retorna_dado = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabela_A a
LEFT JOIN tabela_B b ON a.cod = b.cod_tabela_A
WHERE ano = @ano AND mes = @mes)

print @retorna_dado

if (@retorna_dado > 0)

SELECT * FROM tabela_A a
LEFT JOIN tabela_B b ON a.cod = b.cod_tabela_A
WHERE ano = @ano AND mes = @mes

else
SELECT * FROM tabela_A a
LEFT JOIN tabela_B b ON a.cod = b.cod_tabela_A
```

Se voce declarar o ano 2016 e mes 02 (ou qualquer um que exista na tabela) ele irá trazer com o where, se não existir ele vai ignorar o where

Veja se ajuda

Answer (score -2):

Cara, quebrei a cabeça com um problema parecido e consegui chegar a uma solução. Provavelmente você já resolveu ou fez de outra forma, mas eu quis insistir.

Vou pegar seu exemplo e criar umas variáveis para especificar melhor, ok?

Sua consulta:

SELECT *
FROM tabela_A a
LEFT JOIN tabela_B b ON a.cod = b.cod_tabela_A
WHERE ano = 2016
AND mes = 2

Declare @ano int,
@mes int

Select @ano = 2016, @mes = 2

SELECT *
FROM tabela_A a
LEFT JOIN tabela_B b ON a.cod = b.cod_tabela_A
Where (isNull(@ano, -1) = isNull(b.ano, -1)
Or isNull(@ano, b.ano) = b.ano)
And (isNull(@mes, -1) = isNull(b.mes, -1)
Or isNull(@mes, b.mes) = b.mes)

Vai funcionar. no meu caso eu recebo as variáveis de uma aplicação em C# e podem vir nulas. Essas variáveis nulas pertencem a uma tabela do Left Join (como a tabela_B do seu exemplo)

Espero ter ajudado.