# Select com INNER JOIN, trazendo campos que possuem chave estrangeira NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, inner

Tenho uma tabela itens, pedido_itens, interessado (ela possui auto relacionamento, é usada para secretaria, setor e funcionário, e uma tabela pedido), na tabela pedido possuo 3 chaves estrangeiras(uma para secretaria, outra para setor e mais uma pra funcionário), onde obrigatoriamente a chave estrangeira de secretaria é sempre preenchida, e as outras são opcionais, ficando com null quando não são preenchidas.

Preciso criar um select que me traga um resultado até mesmo quando essas chaves estrangeiras para setor e funcionário na tabela pedido forem NULL.

O select que eu fiz só me mostra os registros que possuem valor em id_secretaria, id_setor e id_funcionario na tabela pedido:

```
SELECT pedido.id as id_pedido, pedido.id_secretaria, pedido.id_setor, pedido.id_funcionario, pedido.dataretirada, 
   pedido_itens.id_item, pedido_itens.quantidade,  pedido_itens.datadevolucao,
   item.nome as item_nome,  
   secretaria.nome as secretaria,
   setor.nome as setor,
   funcionario.nome as funcionario
   FROM pedido 
   INNER JOIN pedido_itens ON (pedido.id = pedido_itens.id_pedido)
   INNER JOIN item ON (pedido_itens.id_item = item.id)
   INNER JOIN interessado as secretaria ON (pedido.id_secretaria = secretaria.id)
   INNER JOIN interessado as setor ON (pedido.id_setor = setor.id) 
   INNER JOIN interessado as funcionario ON (pedido.id_funcionario = funcionario.id);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize o `left join` ao invés do `inner join`

```
select pedido.id as id_pedido, pedido.id_secretaria, pedido.id_setor, pedido.id_funcionario, pedido.dataretirada, 
   pedido_itens.id_item, pedido_itens.quantidade,  pedido_itens.datadevolucao,
   item.nome as item_nome,  
   secretaria.nome as secretaria,
   setor.nome as setor,
   funcionario.nome as funcionario
   FROM pedido 
   INNER JOIN pedido_itens ON (pedido.id = pedido_itens.id_pedido)
   INNER JOIN item ON (pedido_itens.id_item = item.id)
   LEFT JOIN interessado as secretaria ON (pedido.id_secretaria = secretaria.id)
   LEFT JOIN interessado as setor ON (pedido.id_setor = setor.id) 
   LEFT JOIN interessado as funcionario ON (pedido.id_funcionario = funcionario.id);
```

Comment: funcionou, obrigado

Answer (score 3):

Existe a opção de você pode usar **LEFT JOIN**, dá uma olhada neste post [clique aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/116575/como-trazer-registros-de-um-left-join-mesmo-n%C3%A3o-obedecendo-o-where), ainda assim você precisaria verificar a sua regra de negócio, e tem ainda a questão da performance.